# Rails 3.2 how to call before_validation for only new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sti

Rails 3.x `before_validation(:on => :create) do` does not work. Any other ideas appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a condition to the callback with:

```
before_validation :do_something, :unless => Proc.new { |model| model.persisted? }
```

Answer (score 7):

This is what I did an works great.

```
before_validation do
  if self.new_record?      
    # do something here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Now in newer version of rails, you can add:

```
before_validation :anything, on: :create
```

it works, checked it on rails 6+